# Error Loading SDK 9 Sample App

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-sdk-2.3

Specifically, loading the tictactoemain sample.

I get the following error:

[2010-12-27 19:48:35 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read D:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
[2010-12-27 19:48:35 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read D:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
[2010-12-27 19:49:15 - TicTacToe] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'

I only have 'android-9' SDK loaded, but the manifest file only sets the min SDK to 8.

I get this when I try to create a project out of the SDK files.

What configuration tells Eclipse to look in 'D:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\'?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  The TicTacToeMain SDK Sample requires the TicTacToeLib to already be loaded to resolve the dependencies.  Looks like you just open it as a project to make it available to the main version.

Answer (score 1):

> I only have 'android-9' SDK loaded, but the manifest file only sets the min SDK to 8.

That is not your problem. Your problem is that the project targets `android-8`. Go into the Android area of your project properties and change the target to an SDK you have installed.

> What configuration tells Eclipse to look in 'D:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\'?

Window | Preferences | Android -- there is a field here for the path to your Android SDK installation.

Comment: The project target is blank and only the minSDK is set (i.e. to 8).  Selecting browse only allows me to define string resources in the project, not the location of 9.  Window|Preferences|Android is set correctly.  Should I be importing a project or something beside "new"?

Comment: @macombej: As I wrote, go into the Android area of your project properties (right-mouse over your project in the Package Explorer and choose Properties) and change the target to an SDK you have installed.